# awk: if total number of lines is greater print file

Tags: awk

I want to print a file if total number of lines is greater than some number. For example:

```
 cat FILE
 A
 B
 C

 awk '{c+=1} END {print c}' FILE
 3
```

I want to filter FILEs on `c`. If `c` is `>`, `<` and so on.

For example:

```
awk '{c+=1} END if c (c>2) print $0' FILE
```

But I am getting an error message with this command.

Comment: Note that `awk` comes with the `NR` variable, indicating the line number.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No need of `awk` for this:

```
[ $(wc -l < file) -ge 2 ] && cat file
    ^^^^^^^^^^    ^^^^^      ^^^^^^^^
    number of lines  |        print file if condition matched
               compare value
```

Also, note that your syntax cannot make it because `END` block is evaluated *after* reading the file (thus the *END*), so if you `print`, you cannot print anything but the last line.

```
awk '{c+=1} END if c (c>2) print $0' FILE
```

Note that the `END` block must store its commands within brackets, `print` is the same as `print $0` and that `NR` in `awk` contains the number of records, in your case number of lines.

All together, to have your command working and printing the last line in case number of lines is bigger than 2, you can use:

```
awk 'END{if (NR>2) {print}}' FILE
```

#### Test

```
$ [ $(wc -l a | cut -d' ' -f1) -ge 2 ] && cat a
A
B
C

$ [ $(wc -l a | cut -d' ' -f1) -ge 5 ] && cat a
```

Comment: Isn't the `cut` pipeline a bit useless here?  (The usual UUOC here would imply *Useless Use of Cut*)

Comment: If you use `wc -l < a`, you don't need to `cut`. For small files this would look nicer, for big files I don't know if you loose much.

Comment: Uhms @Bernhard, devnull good point. Updated my answer and the "picture" with the arrows :)

Comment: @Pgibas please update your question with proper input so we can guess. See also my `awk` proposal.

Comment: @Pgibas This is the answer to the question you asked. Please, see: http://mywiki.wooledge.org/XyProblem